# Need to refresh div content without loading external url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 List menu with options

See live here [Js Fiddle live](http://jsfiddle.net/adeelmughal4u/9WEqD/)

F-1 = States
F-2 = Each state having 2, 3 prodcuts.

I want to do that when someone select any state from F-1 then F-2 will just show same states if its 2 or 3.

Example:
Select Albama from F-1
Show just Albama states with products in F-2

```
$('#shipping_state').on('change', function() {

    // Do something to refresh F-2 for loading original innerHTML

    var getNme = $('#shipping_state option:selected').text(); // get state text from F-1

    $( ".shipMethod option").not(":contains('" + getNme + "')").each(function(){ // check state is in F-2 exists

        $(this).remove();

    });
});
```

1st time when i select any state from F-2 then F-2 show exact states but when i select another state then F-2 hide all things... Its because i use contains jquery for matching states in F-2 and 1st time its find but 2nd time all states hide other then selected states so contains jquery not working.

Is it possible to refresh F-2 when onchange apply on F-1 or something else i can do for it, but i cannot add load external URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/W9WPf/)</kbd>

```
var ship_method = $(".shipMethod");
$('#shipping_state').on('change', function () {
    var getNme = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    ship_method.find('option').prop('disabled', false);//enable all options
    ship_method.find('option').not(":contains('" + getNme + "')").prop('disabled', true);//disable option not containing getNme
    ship_method.find('option:not([disabled])').first().prop('selected', true);//select 1st enabled option
});
```

---

<kbd>[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/W9WPf/2)</kbd>

```
var ship_method = $(".shipMethod");
$('#shipping_state').on('change', function () {
    var getNme = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    ship_method.find('option').show().prop('disabled', false); //enable all options
    ship_method.find('option').not(":contains('" + getNme + "')").hide().prop('disabled', true); //disable option not containing getNme
    ship_method.prepend(ship_method.find('option:not([disabled])')).find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: its working fine, but what about list option size? when select albama its showing all albama but dropdown size not exact... you can check in your example...

Comment: its exactly what i want... thanx allot :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/9WEqD/12/ (select Alabama, then Arizona)

I don't have time to update each element, but I added another attribute to the .shipping_state options `data-state="STATE_ABBR"` and select the appropriate option when they match the value of #shipping_state. You could change this to use `filter` if you just want to narrow down the available options.

Comment: i appreciate but there is 2, 3 list options with same states but having different products, and i want to hide all other, mean when select albama its show just all albama options not others.

Comment: Like I said, you could use `filter` instead and use `hide` or `show` based on that value. Using an additional attribute is going to be the most efficient means of filtering down your result set. I will update my example

Comment: okay, i have seen, when select albama its working, but when select another one from f-1 then? check it... in your example... its showing nothing?

Comment: dear this should be working for all states, not just 1 or 2... if f-1 state matched with f-2 states (value of text) = show all matching states in f-2. each states have 2, 3 times in f-2 options.

Comment: I'm not going to do the whole thing for you, just showing you an example of how you could fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You use the remove() method, which deletes the option nodes entirely. What you want is to use the show() and hide() methods.

```
$('#shipping_state').on('change', function() {

// Do something to refresh F-2 for 

var getNme = $('#shipping_state option:selected').text(); // get state text from F-1

$( ".shipMethod option").show();
$( ".shipMethod option").not(":contains('" + getNme + "')").each(function(){ // check state is in F-2 exists
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: i already tried this method... this will not show exact size of options you can check here http://jsfiddle.net/adeelmughal4u/9WEqD/6/ when we select state from f-1 its showing 1 in option but use you scroll up down within option you can see all... but size problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/9WEqD/7/. 
Small modification to your code, option are hidden instead of removed.

```
$('#shipping_state').on('change', function() {

    var getNme = $('#shipping_state option:selected').text(); // get state text from F-1

   $( ".shipMethod option").show().not(":contains('" + getNme + "')").hide();//show all then hide
    $("#shipping_method_0").val("");//select empty option by default
});
```

Comment: and what about option size... because its showing all states in drop down but size not adjusted... have to scroll for 2nd 3rd option.